# Opening WebView from Push Notification (Android/Firebase)

Tags: java, swift, firebase, push-notification

**I've developed an Android app which receives Push Notification via Firebase. How can I open/trigger a WebView from that Push Notification?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the URL link in the custom data field while composing a push notification from the firebase and can create an intent filter to the main activity for the specific URL. This will open the app for you. You can retrieve the data (URL in your case) in the main activity and can open a webview with the URL.

You can extract URL from the remote message by using below code in `onMessageRecieved` method

```
String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("<YOUR_KEY>");
```

Comment: That's brilliant  I am very pleased with your answer can you please suggest a code for android or IOS